# How to debug a flow that is triggered after creation of a CaseComment?

Tags: visual-workflow, debug, case-comment

Something is not going right in my flow and it's not crashing, so I don't get an e-mail with a trace.

But if I want to debug my flow, the dialog asks me to select a CaseComment. Which is impossible, because I want to create a new one.

How do I do this?

Comment: So whatever existing record you select, will "act" as if it was inserted for your testing purposes. However, in my attempts to debug specifically a `CaseComment` Flow, it doesn't seem to work as I'm unable to actually select a `CaseComment` record (it seems to select the parent `Case` record instead). Works fine for other objects, however.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves So, another odd behavior of CaseComment then... Encountered one yesterday as well, regarding custom notifications. You answered that one as well :-)

Comment: I'll post an answer as I presume it'll just be a limitation specific to this object since, as you noted, there's certainly others due to it not really being like other objects - but, I'll try to see if I can confirm it's expected or if there's any workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CaseComment` seems to be a weird exception to this functionality - as it doesn't appear to allow you to select a `CaseComment` record. It always ends up being the parent Case record. When you search case comment records to select, the only clickable item is the Case Number.

[image]

With no way to customize the layout that displays, it then clearly shows a `Case` record selected in the `Triggering Record` box.

[image]

This is either just a bug or an unfortunate limitation when it comes to `CaseComment` as it already has other limitations as an object as noted in the idea to [Make Case Comment Object and Page Layouts Customizable](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgueUAB/make-case-comment-object-and-page-layouts-customizable)

---

The expected behavior is that whatever record you select (even though it already exists) will *act as if it's inserted* so you can appropriately test whatever logic should happen after that record is inserted.

In [Debug Record-Triggered Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_debug_record_triggered_flows.htm&type=5&release=232), they mention this

> Under Triggering Record, **you can choose a record for the debug run,
> which triggers the flow as if the record is created**, updated, or
> deleted

As well as having text under `Triggering Record` that mentions the same behavior.

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't an answer to my question. But I flag it as such, as you put much effort into it. How I solved my immediate problem: I activated debug logging in Setup for the user that creates the CaseComment. The debug log turns out to be pretty detailed for flows and it actually told me what I needed to know to solve my problem.

Comment: Definitely feel free to add that as a separate answer (and accept it). I was hyper-focused on the flow-provided debug tool so it's good you have a way to debug in the end specifically for `CaseComment`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, unfortunately I don't have a solution for it.  I logged a new Idea here:  https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000N6HH3UAN/ability-to-set-a-casecomment-record-as-the-triggering-record-when-debugging-flow

Please upvote!